# Knockout.js won't be recognized after using require.js

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-3.2

Calling require.js before knockout.js throws the following message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined

Assuming I have knockout.js at the very top of the combined file, I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            text: '/bower_components/text/text'
        },
    });

    requirejs([
        '/bower_components/text/text.js'
    ]);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dist/combined.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What *else* than `knockout.js` is in the `combined.min.js` file?

Comment: Nevermind, I ended up getting rid of require.js and creating my own component loader... much easier and I saved around 25Kb of crap. Life is beautiful again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Knockout detects RequireJS, it doesn't create a global `ko` object but expects you to use `define` to get the object.